# Bewildered by Vec<Box<dyn T>> and TypeId behaviour

Tags: rust

```rust
use std::any::Any;
use std::any::TypeId;

trait Task {}

struct SomeTask;
impl Task for SomeTask {}

fn main() {
    let tasks_a: Vec<Box<SomeTask>> = vec![Box::new(SomeTask)];
    let tasks_b: Vec<Box<dyn Any>> = vec![Box::new(SomeTask)];
    let tasks_c: Vec<Box<dyn Task>> = vec![Box::new(SomeTask)];

    println!(
        "Item stored in `Vec<Box<SomeTask>>` is of type `SomeTask`? {}",
        TypeId::of::<SomeTask>() == (&*tasks_a[0]).type_id(),
    );

    println!(
        "Item stored in `Vec<Box<dyn Any>>` is of type `SomeTask`? {}",
        TypeId::of::<SomeTask>() == (&*tasks_b[0]).type_id(),
    );

    println!(
        "Item stored in `Vec<Box<dyn Task>>` cast as `&dyn Any` is of type `SomeTask`? {}",
        TypeId::of::<SomeTask>() == (&tasks_c[0] as &dyn Any).type_id(),
    );

    println!(
        "Item stored in `Vec<Box<dyn Task>>` is of type `SomeTask`? {}",
        TypeId::of::<SomeTask>() == (&*tasks_c[0]).type_id(),
    );
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f45b728e8cb5a0bb0523e1c778886b7))

Output:

```
Item stored in `Vec<Box<SomeTask>>` is of type `SomeTask`? true
Item stored in `Vec<Box<dyn Any>>` is of type `SomeTask`? true
Item stored in `Vec<Box<dyn Task>>` cast as `&dyn Any` is of type `SomeTask`? false
Item stored in `Vec<Box<dyn Task>>` is of type `SomeTask`? false
```

Can you help shed some light on the output? Specifically, I don't understand why item of `T` stored in `Vec<Box<dyn Any>>` is of type `T`, but that's not true for item stored in `Vec<Box<dyn Trait>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `(&*tasks_b[0]).type_id()`, you call `<dyn Any as Any>::type_id(&self)`. This calls the `type_id()` method on the `dyn Any` through the dynamic vtable.

When you call `(&*tasks_a[0]).type_id()`, you call `<SomeTask as Any>::type_id(&self)`. This calls this function statically, since the type is known.

The key is the `(&*tasks_c[0]).type_id()` call. `&*tasks[0]` is of type `&dyn Task`. This type does not define a dynamic `type_id()` method, because it is not `dyn Any`. So, the same as with the static `SomeTask`, we call a static `type_id()`. What is `Self`? Well, `Self` is `dyn Task`. This is a concrete type - `dyn Trait` is not just some type implementing the trait, it is a type itself that represents a type-erased type implementing the trait. And just like any other type, it has a `TypeId`. If you'll compare the result of `(&*tasks_c[0]).type_id()` to `TypeId::of::<dyn Task>()`, you'll see they're equal.

`(&tasks_c[0] as &dyn Any).type_id()` is similar, but not exactly the same: here we take `&tasks_c[0]`, which has the type `&Box<dyn Task>`, and coerce it to `&dyn Any` - that is, the erased type is `Box<dyn Task>`, and indeed the `TypeId` is `TypeId::of::<Box<dyn Task>>`.

If you want `type_id()` on `dyn Task` to calculate the actual type ID of the erased type, you can make `Any` a supertrait of `Task`. This will not allow you to make a `dyn Task` into a `dyn Any`, however. This requires the unstable [trait upcasting coercion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65991). Until then, the usual way is to expose a method to upcast `dyn Task` into `dyn Any` in the trait:

```rust
trait Task: Any {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

impl Task for SomeTask {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any { self as &dyn Any }
}

tasks_c[0].as_any().type_id();
```